# Removing a part of url in php

Tags: php

I want to remove `%`, `+`, `ascii codes` from `url`.

Example:

From

```
 http://prexprint.com/Laminated%20Business%20Cards
```

to

```
 http://prexprint.com/Laminated Business Cards
```

Comment: plz share own review about this question

Comment: Have your tried using unescape?

Comment: Replace `%20` with `-`.

Comment: i am using unescape  ..but i hv'nt solution ..so plz send another logic about  this problma

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There you go with JS:

```
var orgUrl = 'http://prexprint.com/Laminated%20Business%20Cards';
var reqUrl = decodeURI(orgUrl);
console.log(reqUrl);
```

Edit:

```
var orgUrl = 'http://prexprint.com/Laminated%20Business%20Cards';
var reqUrl = decodeURI(orgUrl)
reqUrl = reqUrl.replace(/\ /g, '-');
console.log(reqUrl)
window.location.href = reqUrl
```

Comment: i am using decodeURl but on google chrome  .now showing %20 in url bar so plz check in google chrome...please and Thankyou

Comment: Well when I try the above code in chrome's developer console, it gives me this output - http://prexprint.com/Laminated Business Cards

Comment: this output  prexprint.com/Laminated Business Cards showing on url bar on google chrome..?

Comment: Chrome address bar?? Can you elaborate in your question what are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: ok....i want to remove %20 from Laminated%20Business%20Cards on url bar on google chrome browser ..i want to look like this 
Laminated Business Cards on url bar

Comment: Well thats the behavior of chrome. You can try to add '-' in url as stackoverflow do.

http://prexprint.com/Laminated-Business-Cards

Comment: ok i will   try   ..but  i used lot of logic and function ..but still problm

Comment: i have a question about redirecting the page like  window.location.href = reqUrl

Answer (score 1):

Browser will always render in `URL`  `spaces` with `%20` we can't change it.

if you want to change it `http://prexprint.com/Laminated Business Cards` than instead of this make your url

`http://prexprint.com/Laminated+Business+Cards`

or

`http://prexprint.com/LaminatedBusinessCards`

```
$x = 'http://prexprint.com/Laminated%20Business%20Cards';
$y =str_replace('%20',' ',$x);
echo $y;
```

or use

```
<?php echo rawurldecode('http://prexprint.com/Laminated%20Business%20Cards');  ?>
```

Comment: $x = 'http://prexprint.com/Laminated%20Business%20Cards';
  //$x = str_replace(" ","+",$title1);
  //prd($x);

Comment: i use this type of logic

Comment: $x = 'http://prexprint.com/Laminated%20Business%20Cards';
  //$x = str_replace(" ","+",$title1);
  //prd($x);  but in google chrome  does'nt remove %20..so plz check in google chrome..Thankyou

Comment: Browser will always render in URL spaces with %20 we can't change it.

Tushar Plz explain ...?

Comment: @TusharGupta See my comment here > http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17962689/removing-a-part-of-url-in-php/17962978?noredirect=1#comment26255348_17962978

Comment: @user2636734 every `space` in the `ur` is changed to '%20' by default we can't change this behavior.

Answer (score 1):

URLs in address bar cannot be with spaces. You can use URL Rewrite such that you can make your URL look like this http://prexprint.com/Laminated-Business-Cards. Even if you place a link like this **`http://prexprint.com/Laminated Business Cards`**, the browsers will automatically replaces the spaces with '%20'

Comment: The strangest thing happened. I opened up `http://prexprint.com/Laminated Business Cards` in my browser (FF v22), it showed the `%20` where the spaces are for 1/2 a second, then showed `http://prexprint.com/Laminated Business Cards` exactly as shown in my address bar; bizarre. Probably because of my browser's version? I can't explain.

Comment: plz give one exapmle...?

Comment: @Fred: I am astonished. :O

Comment: @user2636734: The URl of this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17962689/removing-a-part-of-url-in-php is a better example.

Comment: @SuryaS So am I. My guess is, it's because of either my web browser version, or the server's configuration itself. It can only be one of those reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Use [urldecode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) function of PHP

```
<?php
echo urldecode('http://prexprint.com/Laminated%20Business%20Cards');
?>
```

Comment: Thanks shankar...but i hv'nt solution because urlencode  does not remove %20 on url bar in chrome ...so plz check on google chrome

Comment: When you are representing the url `http://prexprint.com/Laminated Business Cards` in the address, it automatically adds `%20` to the spaces and similarly if the URL is like this `http://prexprint.com/Laminated Business Cards#12663` it will replace the # as `%23`.

Comment: Laminated Business Cards#12663 ..? please elabrote ..?

Comment: @TbsAmit, # is a symbol so it will automatically get encoded to %23.

Comment: ok .. now you can give a expamle with # ..but i want only + or  - in url bar..?

Comment: @TbsAmit, `-` will be left as it is, but `+` will be encoded to `%2B`

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
<?php echo urldecode('http://prexprint.com/Laminated%20Business%20Cards'); ?>
```

Comment: Thankyou 

urldecode is not works on this problam ...so plz check on google chrome   %20 is not remove from url bar on chrome

Answer (score 0):

You should have the urls encoded, for compatability issues.

"If it ain't broke, don't fix it."